# How can i easily use my custom class methods among pyspark operations?

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-types

I have a class Age, a csv file and a pyspark runtime session

ages.csv

```
Name;Age
alpha;noise20noise
beta;noi 3 sE 0
gamma;n 4 oi 0 se
phi;n50ise
detla;3no5ise
kappa;No 4 i 5 sE
omega;25noIsE
```

Which is read virtually as (after parsing Age column):

```
Name;Age
alpha;20
beta;30
gamma;40
phi;50
detla;35
kappa;45
omega;25
```

Defined class: Age
age.py

```
import re

class Age:
    # age is a number representing the age of a person
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.age == self.__parse(other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.age < self.__parse(other)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.age > self.__parse(other)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.age <= self.__parse(other)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.age >= self.__parse(other)

    def __parse(self, age):
        return int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d', age)))

# Let's test this class
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Age(18) == 'noise18noise')
    print(Age(18) <= 'aka 1 fakj 8 jal')
    print(Age(18) >= 'jaa 18 ka')
    print(Age(18) < '1 kda 9')
    print(Age(18) > 'akfa 1 na 7 noise')

Output:
True
True
True
True
True
```

The test did work. I want to use it in pyspark

Run pyspark, read ages.csv and import Age

```
Using Python version 3.6.7 (default, Oct 23 2018 19:16:44)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> ages = spark.read.csv('ages.csv', sep=';', header=True)
19/01/28 14:44:18 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
>>> ages.show()
+-----+------------+
| Name|         Age|
+-----+------------+
|alpha|noise20noise|
| beta|  noi 3 sE 0|
|gamma| n 4 oi 0 se|
|  phi|      n50ise|
|detla|     3no5ise|
|kappa| No 4 i 5 sE|
|omega|     25noIsE|
+-----+------------+
```

Now i want to get all people whose age is 20, for example

```
>>> from age import Age
>>> ages.filter(ages.Age == Age(20)).show()
```

And this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 116, in _
    njc = getattr(self._jc, name)(jc)
File "/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1248, in __call__
File "/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1218, in _build_args
File "/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1218, in <listcomp>
File "/opt/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 298, in get_command_part
AttributeError: 'Age' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

So my **1st Problem** is how to solve this error

This is my first attempt to solve this problem: i changed the definition of `class Age` to extend `str` like this:

age.py

```
...
class Age(str):
    ....
```

As a second attempt:

```
>>> ages.filter(ages.Age == Age(20)).show()
+----+---+
|Name|Age|
+----+---+
+----+---+
```

Nevertherless we still have:

```
>>> 'noise20noise' == Age(20)
True
```

As you can see the `AttributeError: 'Age' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'` disappears but it doesn't compute the right answer, which is my **2nd Problem**

Again here's my attempt:
I use pyspark user defined functions

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> import pyspark.sql.types as T
>>> eq20 = F.udf(lambda c: c == Age(20), T.BooleanType())
>>> ages.filter(eq20(ages.Age)).show()
+-----+------------+
| Name|         Age|
+-----+------------+
|alpha|noise20noise|
+-----+------------+
```

Now this works.
But here's the thing:
I like most the first idiom

```
>>> ages.filter(ages.Age == Age(20)).show()
```

which is simpler and more expressive. I don't want to define a function like `eq20, eq21, less_than50, greater_than30, etc` every single time

I could do that definition in the class Age itself but i don't know how to do that. Nevertheless this is what i've tried so far using a `python decorator`

age.py

```
# other imports here
...

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def connect_to_pyspark(function):
    return F.udf(function, T.BooleanType())

class Age(str):
    ...

    @connect_to_pyspark
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.age == self.__parse(other)

    ...
    # do the same decorator for the other comparative methods
```

Test again:

```
>>> ages.filter(ages.Age == Age(20)).show()
+----+---+
|Name|Age|
+----+---+
+----+---+
```

And it doesn't work. Or my decorator is badly written?

How to solve all this?
Is my solution to first problem good enough? If no what sould be done instead? If yes how to solve the second problem?

Answer (score 1):

Getting `ages.Age == Age(20)` is going to be pretty hard because spark doesn't respect python conventions for implementing `__eq__`. More on this later, but if you're ok doing `Age(20) == ages.Age` then you have some options. IMHO, the easiest way to do this is to only wrap the parse logic in an udf:

```
parse_udf = F.udf(..., T.IntegerType())
class Age:
    ...
    def __eq__(self, other: Column):
        return F.lit(self.age) == parse_udf(other)
```

Notice that `Age` doesn't subclass `str`, that's just going to cause a world of hurt. If you want to use a decorator, your decorator should not return a `udf`, it should return a function that applies a udf. Like so:

```
import re
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def connect_to_pyspark(function):
  def helper(age, other):
    myUdf = F.udf(lambda item_from_other: function(age, item_from_other), T.BooleanType())
    return myUdf(other)
  return helper

class Age:

    def __init__(self, age):
      self.age = 45

    def __parse(self, other):
      return int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d', other)))

    @connect_to_pyspark
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.age == self.__parse(other)

ages.withColumn("eq20", Age(20) == df.Age).show()
```

More on why you need to use `Ages(20) == ages.Age`. In python if you do `a == b` and the class of a doesn't know how to compare to b, it should return `NotImplemented` and then python will try `b.__eq__(a)`, but spark never returns `NotImplemented` so the `__eq__` of `Age` will only get invoked if you have it first in the expression :(.

Comment: This only works for one way ```Age(20) == df.Age``` but not the other ```df.Age == Age(20)``` where I'm still getting the following error ```AttributeError: 'Age' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' ```. The latter is what i really need because then i could even do things like ```df.Age.between(Age(20), Age(30))```. I wish this could be solved.

Comment: @mctrjalloh raise it on the spark mailing list, there's no way to fix that without updating pyspark :(

Comment: Ok. I will try to raise the issue.